# Managing VueJs Watchers Dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component with a table row where I have multiple fields. By 
updating one field will update another field with a value based on margin or sell price.

But as I am watching all fields I am getting a bouncing effect. Adding _debounce helps but does not stop the problem. To try and manage the problem I am using the callback to the watchers to trigger the unwatch() but when I re-add the watchers the callbacks stop un-watching.

I have a working gist as an example of the code.

[view example gist](https://jsfiddle.net/openeye/LqLjeqrf/)

```
Vue.component('pricing', {

  template: '#pricing-row',

  props: ['item'],

  mounted() {
    this.addWatchers()
  },

  methods: {

      resetWatchers() {
        setTimeout(()=> {
            this.addWatchers()
        }, 700)
    },

    addWatchers() {

      this.updateNet = this.$watch(
        function() {
            return this.item.net
        },
        function() {
            // unmount other watchers
            this.updateMargin()
            this.updateSell()
            // calculate sell price and update
            this.setSellPrice()
            // re-add watchers
            this.resetWatchers()
        }
      ),

      this.updateMargin = this.$watch(
        function() {
            return this.item.margin
        },
        function() {
          // unmount other watchers which can cause bounce effect
          this.updateSell()
          // calculate sell price and update
          this.setSellPrice()
          // re-add watchers
          this.resetWatchers()
        }
      ),

      this.updateSell = this.$watch(
        function() {
            return this.item.sell
        },
        function(sellPrice) {
          // unmount other watchers which can cause bounce effect
          this.updateMargin()
          // update margin
          this.setMargin(sellPrice)
          // re-add watchers
          this.resetWatchers()
        }
      )
    },

    setSellPrice() {
      let price = (100 / (100 - this.item.margin)) * this.item.net
      this.item.sell = price.toFixed(2)
    },

    setMargin(sellPrice) {
      let profit = (sellPrice - this.item.net)
      let price = (100 * profit) / sellPrice
      this.item.margin = price.toFixed(2)
    }
  }

})

new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data: {
    prices: [
        { 
        id: 1,
        net: 5,
        margin: 10,
        sell: 5.56
      },
        { 
        id: 2,
        net: 7,
        margin: 10,
        sell: 7.78
      },      
    ]
  }
})
```

I believe I am using the watchers correctly by mounting them on `mounted()` calling a method. And re-initialising by recalling that method?

I really hope you can help.

Comment: This seems very unfortunate solution. Can you describe me just relations between the `net`, `margin` and `sell` attributes?

Comment: Basically by updating the sell price it will automatically re-calculate the sell price based off net and margin.. The same for the other fields.

Comment: This is infinite loop. Now I understand where is the problem... Simpliest solution is considering the `sell` property as raw price, that you cant use directly, and as real sell price you must use computed property based on net, margin and raw price.

Comment: have you considered using computed instead of watch? Seems like the more elegant solution.

Comment: Its the same problem Daniel.. Using computed getter and setter has the same side effect of multiple inputs.

Comment: hmm, not what I'm getting, I'll post code in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a solution using computed values

each parameter (net, margin, sell) are abstracted through a computed value. the getter returns the this.item value, the setter first updates this.item value and then updates the related values.

This is a similar issue as a color picker, you can see a more complex version of this problem here http://jsfiddle.net/Phunky/2enc99r1/

```js
Vue.component('pricing', {
 template: '#pricing-row',
  props: ['item'],
  computed: {
   net:{
     get () {
       return Number(this.item.net)
      },
      set (net) {
       this.item.net = Number(net)
        this.setSellPrice()
      }
    },
   margin:{
     get () {
       return this.item.margin
      },
      set (margin) {
       this.item.margin = Number(margin)
        this.setSellPrice()
      }
    },
   sell:{
     get () {
       return this.item.sell
      },
      set (sell) {
       this.item.sell = Number(sell)
       this.setMargin()
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    
    setSellPrice() {
      let price = (100 / (100 - this.margin)) * this.net
      this.item.sell = price.toFixed(2)
    },
    
    setMargin() {
      let profit = (this.sell - this.net)
      let price = (100 * profit) / this.sell
      this.item.margin = Number(price.toFixed(2))
    }
  }
  
})

new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data: {
   prices: [
     { 
       id: 1,
        net: 5,
        margin: 10,
        sell: 5.56
      },
     { 
       id: 2,
        net: 7,
        margin: 10,
        sell: 7.78
      },      
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.5/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="pricing-row">
  <tr>
   <td><input v-model="net" /></td>
    <td><input v-model="margin"  /></td>
    <td><input v-model="sell"  /></td>
  </tr> 
</script>


<div id="vue">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Net</th>
      <th>Margin</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr is="pricing" v-for="(price, index) in prices" :item="price" :key="price.id"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I have done the same. But Im still getting a bouncing effect. See screencast.  http://d.pr/i/1l04rR

Comment: Ok so after all these hours of frustration I found the route cause.. I am using  bootstrap-vue.. Looks like they have an even firing on input causing it.. Please pass me a gun !!  TY

Comment: I try to avoid using these libraries, in preference to css-only frameworks like https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/ or if I need the added functionality then use something like elemnet.io which is purpose built built for vue, and not patched like vue ports of material or bootstrap.